# I want to add facebook like button on a page in my website, but have the URL go to a totally different page in my website. Is it possible to do this?

Tags: url, dynamic, facebook-like

I want to add facebook like button on a page in my website, but have the URL go to a totally different page in my website that has more detail. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: what platform are you working on ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a "data-href" attribute to the fb-like div, like so:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.DOMAIN.com/PATH/TO/MORE/DETAILED/PAGE" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Documentation found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/?locale2=es_ES)